# Why can't I execute kill command in a docker container from host's command line?

Tags: bash, docker

This does the job.

```js
//get inside container
$ docker exec -it -u root container bash

// run kill ( works perfectly )
# kill -9 $(pgrep gunicorn)
```

But I want to do it directly without having to login to container's shell.

I try this.

```
$ docker exec -it -u root container bash -c "kill -9 $(pgrep gunicorn)"
```

I get this error.

```
bash: line 0: kill: (1227) - No such process
bash: line 1: 1988: command not found
bash: line 2: 8789: command not found
bash: line 3: 8989: command not found
bash: line 4: 11471: command not found
bash: line 5: 97065: command not found
bash: line 6: 729921: command not found
bash: line 7: 750108: command not found
bash: line 8: 851794: command not found
bash: line 9: 851862: command not found
```

I try another stuff.

```
$ docker exec -it -u root container bash -c "touch test-file"
```

This works perfectly as well.

So why am I not able to run `kill` command like this ?

Comment: At a guess, because `pgrep gunicorn` is executed first *on the host*, and returns a process ID which does not match that found in the container. You could try using single quotes to stop that expression getting evaluated by the shell on the host first?

Comment: You are right. Solved it. Thanks.

Comment: Also note that a Docker container usually only runs a single process, so you should be able to `docker stop container; docker rm container` to stop the one process in the container and clean it up.  You should not need `docker exec` in normal use, nor should you need to look up process IDs inside containers.

Answer (score 0):

As suggest by @SiHa, had to use single quotes to stop expression getting evaluated by the shell on host. Worked fine after replacing double quotes with single quotes.